# how to make the date change

Tags: sql, database, powershell, azure

How to make the date change according to the PC time ??
example:

```
$StorageUri = "https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(2018-01-09-07:00)dbdom_buin.bacpac";
```

How do I make the file that I am going to save change the date automatically without having to change it every day?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you are trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate?

Comment: the date that appears in the code must change it daily so that it keeps it with the real date
How can I make it save the actual date automatically?

Comment: Are you using a Powershell script to back up a SQL Server database and you want to version the backups by date?

Comment: Yes, I'm backing up PowerShell, that code is what I keep with the date that appears, but what I need that date is automatically changing when the script starts without having to change the date on a daily basis

Comment: Have you looked at the Powershell function Get-Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the date as a variable, [format options here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx):

```
$dateVar = Get-Date -format s
```

Then build your `$StorageUri` path from that:

```
$StorageUri = "https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(" + $dateVar + ")dbdom_buin.bacpac"
```